# Created an image cache for a UITableViewCell but only one image is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uitableview

I've had a great help in creating a functional image cache for a  `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndex`. Unfortunately, with the *code* below, only one image is displayed over and over. I was under the impression that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was like a for loop, running again for each `row`.  Therefore, I'm wondering why only one image is displayed.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "restaurantcell") as? RestaurantTableCell
    var oneRestaurant: Restaurant = tablerestaurantarray[indexPath.row]

    if let cachedVersion = cache.object(forKey: "image") {
        oneRestaurant = cachedVersion
    } else {
        cache.setObject(oneRestaurant, forKey: "image")
    }

    cell?.picture?.image = oneRestaurant.value(forKey: "image") as! UIImage?

    let restaurant = restaurantArray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.name?.text = restaurant.value(forKey: "Name") as? String

    return cell!
}
```

Update 2:

[Results from the added breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYCfC.png)

Comment: How high is the cell? What is the default image in your Storyboard? From what I understand, you get the image from the class `Restaurant`. Could you post that class as well?

Comment: just a simple "var image = UIimage?" for the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same NSCache key (`"image"`) for different objects. That's why only the first `Restaurant` object is saved into the cache. For all other cells you look for the object cached for key `"image"` and get the same previously saved `Restaurant` object back.

You have to use different keys for caching different `Restaurant` objects. Try to append the index path to the cache key:

```
let key = "restaurant \(indexPath)"

if let cachedVersion = cache.object(forKey: key) {
    oneRestaurant = cachedVersion
} else {
    cache.setObject(oneRestaurant, forKey: key)
}
```

I don't quite understand why you want to cache restaurant objects though. You already have them in the `tablerestaurantarray`, so there won't be any benefit caching them. Maybe your intention was caching the images?

Comment: These images were downloaded from cloud kit and the tableview animation was choppy until a cache was created.. or at least thats my thinking.

Comment: I should add, the images of the ckrecords were passed through a class to receive the image data.

Comment: the suggested "let key = 'restaurant \(indexpath)" did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Could you please check if oneRestaurant is saved to the cache once for each restaurant object? Set a breakpoint in the else clause.

Comment: Also, make sure you have no typo: It should be "restaurant \(indexPath)", not "restaurant (indexpath)". Note the missing '\' in your comment as well as the lowercase 'p'. The idea is to add the current index path to the key like this: "restaurant [0, 2]"

Comment: I'll post the results of the breakpoint in the updated photo in my question. We luckily did achieve the restaurant[0,2] result. However, the image is still not visible.

Comment: The yellow warning you got is meaningful... Remove the quotation marks from the keys: it should be cache.object(forKey: key) and cache.setObject(oneRestaurant, forKey: key). You want to use the String saved in the 'key' property as the cache key, not a "key" String constant.

Comment: I am incredibly appreciative of your time, nils! Thank you for the help!